# Sum of integers in an array and multiplying integer by 1.5

Tags: java, arrays, sum, decimal

I am having an issue getting the sum of the integers in my array AND an issue getting the product of an integer * 1.5.  My code below could be completely off as I am new to Java and have been at this for hours and hours.  The purpose of the program is to enter the number of hours worked, each day, for 5 days.  With that, and the pay rate, you're supposed to output the average hours worked, total hours, and total pay.  The pay should also include overtime if there is any.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
String name;
String id;
int payRate;
int[] hours = new int[5];
int avgHours;
int totalPay;
int totalHours = 0;
int counter;
int overTime = 0;

//housekeeping
System.out.print("Enter the Employee's name: ");
inputString = input.readLine();
name = inputString;

System.out.print("Enter the Employee's ID: ");
inputString = input.readLine();
id = inputString;

System.out.print("Enter the Employee's pay rate: ");
inputString = input.readLine(); 
payRate = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

//hoursPay
counter = 0;
for(hours[counter] = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
{
    System.out.print("How many hours did the employee work? ");
    inputString = input.readLine();
    hours[counter] = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
}//endfor
    for(totalHours = 0; counter < 5; hours[counter]++);
    {
        totalHours += hours[counter];
        if(totalHours > 40)
        {
            overTime = payRate + (payRate / 2);
        }//endif
    }//endwhile

//print
if(counter == 5)
{
    System.out.println(name + " " + id + " $" + payRate + "/hour" );

    avgHours = totalHours / counter;
    totalPay = totalHours * payRate + overTime; 
    System.out.println...
    System.out.println...
    System.out.println...
```

Comment: You are not incrementing your counter inside of the while loop.

Comment: What Keith said, plus your `if` block test on `totalHours` should probably be outside the loop.

Comment: For future reference, you want to get more technical on what the "issue" is.

Comment: Apologies, I tried to add more of the code but kept getting an error  message.  Update: I've added more of the code.  Hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: When running the program, I am able to input the name, ID, and pay rate.  I am also able to add the hours worked 5 times.  However, the "issue" is a run-time error after entering the fifth "hours worked".  At that point it should output a total hours, average hours, and total pay.

Comment: Your counter variable need to be reset before you start printing the 2nd for loop....can you do that and check again....also debug helps when you code using IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bp_1,
I re-do all the code again and pasted it below. It WORKS. There was some fundamental error you making while coding. Compare your code with mine and you will see the difference.

```
String name;
String id;
int payRate;
int[] hours = new int[5];
int avgHours;
int totalPay;
int totalHours = 0;
int counter;
int overTime = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//housekeeping
System.out.print("Enter the Employee's name: ");
String inputString = input.nextLine();
name = inputString;

System.out.print("Enter the Employee's ID: ");
inputString = input.nextLine();
id = inputString;

System.out.print("Enter the Employee's pay rate: ");
inputString = input.nextLine();
payRate = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

//hoursPay
counter = 0;
for (hours[counter] = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
System.out.print("How many hours did the employee work? ");
inputString = input.nextLine();
hours[counter] = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
}//endfor

counter = 0;// reset counter here
for (totalHours = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
totalHours += hours[counter];
if (totalHours > 40) {
overTime = payRate + (payRate / 2);
}//endif
}//end of for loop

if (counter == 5) {
System.out.println(name + " " + id + " $" + payRate + "/hour");
avgHours = totalHours / counter;
totalPay = totalHours * payRate + overTime;
System.out.println("Average Hours: " + avgHours);
System.out.println("Total pay: " + totalPay);
System.out.println("Total Hours: " + totalHours);
System.out.println("Overtime ($): " + overTime);
}//end of if
```

Comment: you didn't have to go to all that trouble but it is much appreciated.  I will compare the two now so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: @bp_1 In a rush, i forgot to tell you that i deliberately left one logical error in your program. Hint, it is towards **overtime** calculation. Try solving it and you will learn some more towards Java.

Comment: I found the error earlier today.  Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

In place of

```
for(totalHours = 0; counter < 5; hours[counter]++);
```

write

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
```

1. semicolon removed.
2. `counter` incremented instead of `hours[counter]`

Comment: It continues to give me this run-time error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Plumber.<init>(Plumber.java:52)
    at Plumber.main(Plumber.java:76) which is located here: totalHours += hours[counter];

Comment: Check my comment on your OP...it will because the counter variable when exits the first loop is 5, whereas there is no variable on that position in your hours[] array...i.e. no hours[5]== 6th element

Comment: @H-Patel, I followed your suggestion but am still getting the same run time error...